# Trying to add varied placeholder text via JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, attributes, placeholder

As part of my websites setup I am using a login form that is generated using a shortcode; because of this I cannot add the placeholder attribute in the HTML of the form so my only option is to add it using JS/jQuery. Unfortunately this is an area of website development that I am unfamiliar with.

I need to add 2 different placeholder texts, one for the 'Email' field and another for the 'Password' field. To make this easier you can view the form here:

https://members.argentumfx.co.uk

The top field is for the 'Email' placeholder and the bottom field is for the 'Password' placeholder.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

[View Placeholder Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBhT3.png)

`#user_login` is the ID of the Email field; `#user_pass` is the ID of the Password field.

Please can someone provide me with some JS/jQuery to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any libraries:

```
document.getElementById("user_login").setAttribute("placeholder","Email Address");
```

Comment: thank you worked like a charm once I added the <script> code here </script> tags!

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery, you can use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to set the placeholder attribute on each input.

```
$(function() {
  $('input#user_login').attr('placeholder', 'Email Address');
  $('input#user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'Password'); 
});
```